# Apache Tomcat Times Out When Requesting Dspace Files From External IP

Tags: tomcat, iis, dspace

I have a Dspace installation in a windows server 2012 environment.
IIS 8 was previously installed,but the port has been changed to 86, and Apache Tomcat has been configured to listen on port 80.

I can access the Dspace directory and the Tomcat web-root via:

```
    http://localhost/dspaceroot and http://localhost
```

The issue is that when i try to connect to either the tomcat web-root or the Dspace directory over the internet using the external ip-address, i get a timeout error.

i increased the connection timeout parameter in my server config file, but still no success.How can i resolve this issue?.

(N.B. i could access the IIS 8 web-root over the internet, when it was listening on port 80 before i changed it)

Comment: The problem was a firewall issue..thanks

Comment: Post details as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

OP indicated that the problem was related to a firewall configuration issue.